# Align text in center of coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a circle and label the circle with some text. I want the text to be in the middle of the circle, both horizontally and vertically. To do this, I use `axis.text()` and then specify `ha = center, va = center`. However, the vertical alignment is not precisely in the middle.
A MWE:

```
from matplotlib import patches

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

# Create axes for left and right plot
axis1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.axis('off') # Cleaner picture

axis1.set(xlim=[-1,1], ylim=[-1,1], aspect=1) # Force the aspect ratio to be 1:1


## Create a circle
smallcircle = patches.Circle(xy = (0,0), radius = 0.8, facecolor = 'g')
## Add the circle to the plot
axis1.add_patch(smallcircle)

# Create label in small circle
axis1.text(x = 0, y = 0, s = '0', fontsize=55, ha="center", va="center", color = 'k')
```

This gives the following picture:

[image]

It is clear that the horizontal alignment functions properly, but the vertical aligment is not exactly in the center.

Using `va = center` I was expecting the vertical alignment also to be exactly center, but this is not happening.

My guess is that this is due to the fonts/characters themselves. For instance, if I replace the label with `g`, I get this picture:

[image]

which is more properly aligned.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem when the characters that need to be displayed as the label are not 'aligned' themselves?

This method should always work with numbers, and preferrably also combinations like (0,0) or other characters.
Moreover, it should also preferably work with tex and more elaborate markup (e.g. $\mathbf{(0,0)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, `va="center_baseline"` looks to be a solution, see this picture:

[image]

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/text_alignment.html

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. Thanks!